# Using form elements to interact with UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a button on a user control, that by default is not enabled. When an event happens on the Form, I want it to be able to enable the button. I have set a button on the main form to test this, and it appears to set the UC button to enabled, but it doesn't appear enabled in the application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Login ucLogin = new Login();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ucLogin.loginEnabled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("True");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("False");
            ucLogin.loginEnabled = true;
        }


    }
}
```

Form.cs

And in the usercontrol for the login form:

```
public partial class Login : UserControl
{
    public bool loginEnabled
    {
        get { return ucBtn.Enabled; }
        set { ucBtn.Enabled = value; }
    }
}
```

What's strange is if I click the Form button1, it will say "False", if I click it again, it will say "True", indicating that it **does** change the value of the UC button, but on the application, it remains disabled.

Comment: try call `Application.DoEvents()` after changing the value of `ucBtn.Enabled`

Comment: @FelixD. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/  plz don't just suggest Application.DoEvents without mentioning the danger

Comment: @Steve this seem to me like a ' beginner problem' (no offense) so I just kept it simple.

Comment: @FelixD. still. should warn someone about something that might have serious consequences. Just like you should never teach beginners to construct Sql with string concatenation

Comment: @Steve yeah. You're right - my bad. So thx for pointing it out !

Comment: If it's a beginner problem, is there a solution that doesn't require Application.DoEvents? I'm fully capable of understanding a more permanent solution, while C# is not my forte, I'm adept in other languages.

Comment: Your code shows `new Login()` but we have no evidence that this control was actually added to the form's Control collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Login` user control that you see on the form is likely not the instance you are setting `loginEnabled` property on.

Comment: Yep, you were right. I instantiated a new instance in the Form.cs, rather than referencing the one already placed on the form. login1.loginEnabled was the correct way to do this :)